# How to eliminate excessive vertical spacing

Tags: formatting, paragraphs

How would someone go about eliminating excessive spacing (leading) in a document? I don't see any reason why these gaps are there. Below is part of the code that I'm working with, the gaps are after the example subtitle and after of `$\theta$` before solution.

```
\example 
Use the triangle in \rfig{mckeague_cat_img3} to find the values of the
six trigonometric functions of $\theta$.
\solution \rfig{mckeague_cat_img3} gives the lengths of the hypotenuse and the side adjacent to
$\theta$. Use the Pythagorean Theorem to find
the length of the other side:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
12^2 + b^2 &= 13^2 &\\
144 + b^2 &= 169 &\\
b^2 &= 25 &\\
b &= 5 &\\ 
\end{alignat*}
```

These large paragraph breaks (?) are everywhere in my document, this is just a single example.

Comment: Instead of posting code fragments, it's much better to post a complete compilable document that shows the problem.  So embed this fragment in `\documentclass{} ... \begin{document} ... \end{document}` and edit your question to give this code.  For large chunks of code you can select the text and use the {} icon to format it as code.

Comment: the double backslash just before \end{alignat*} adds an extra blank line at that point.  as for the other locations, it's necessary to know the definitions of `\example`, `\solution` and `\rfig` (at least), so the request for a minimum example is seconded.